# JQuery's wildcard symbol to ignore characters in the middle?

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering how to search through all of html LI but only matching the ID attribute.   From google search, I see this for begin and end only but nothing that would use both but ignore the middle part.

Example...

To get all the elements starting with "jander" you should use:

```
$("li[id^=jander]")
```

To get those that end with "jander"

```
$("[id$=jander]")
```

But what about the matching ones that start with "abc" and end with "xyz"?

```
$("li[id???=abc???xyz]")
```

as in

```
$("li[id???=abc???xyz]").on('click', function() { alert('foo'); });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain expressions:

```
$('li[id ^="abc"][id $="xyz"]')
```

```js
$('li[id ^="abc"][id $="xyz"]').each(function(){
  $("ul#results").append('<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Unit tests:
<ul>
  <li id="foo">a</li>
  <li id="bar">b</li>
  <li id="abc?????xyz">c</li>
  <li id="ab???xyz">d</li>
  <li id="abcxyz">e</li>
</ul>

Results:
<ul id="results">
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [jQuery .filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to further filter your elements in the match:

```
$('li[id^="abc"]').filter('[id$="xyz"]').on();
```